# java 8 groupBY or using general approach

Tags: java

I get an arraylist of objects of this class. e.g.:

```
new Foo(1, "P1", 300, 400), 
new Foo(1, "P4", 300, 400),
new Foo(2, "P2", 600, 400),
new Foo(3, "P3", 30, 20),
new Foo(3, "P3", 70, 20),
new Foo(1, "P1", 360, 40),
new Foo(4, "P4", 320, 200),
new Foo(4, "P4", 500, 900)
```

I want to transform these values by creating a new  list of FOO object having summation value grouped by both id and reference.
it will be like:

```
new Foo(1, "P1", 660, 440), 
new Foo(1, "P4", 300, 400),
new Foo(2, "P2", 600, 400), 
new Foo(3, "P3", 100, 40)
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  It will help you write your question in a way that will help us help you.

Comment: @jbrown He wants a method that will accept an `ArrayList` of `Foo`s and will return the grouped version of that `ArrayList`. For example: iterate through all the items of the list, check if the item already exists in the list that will be returned, if it doesn't then add it, if it does merge the numeric values.

Comment: @nickzoum - just introducing the idea of "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem" as explained in the linked doc

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to do such a "special" grouping, you should (or rather: can) not use the built-in `groupBy` function. The semantics of the built-in function do not include the "merge" operation that you want to do on the `Foo` objects.

Instead, you may use the [`Collectors#toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) function:

- The `keyMapper` is a function that creates a key, some sort of "identifier" for the entries. In your case, this is a function that takes a `Foo`, and creates a `Entry<Integer, String>` object, used as the key for the map. (You could use any `Pair` or `Tuple` there - even a `List<Object>` would do it)
- The `valueMapper` can be the identity function
- The `mergeFunction` is the important one here: It takes two `Foo` objects (with the same number and string), and returns a new, merged `Foo` object, where the remaining values have been added.

The result will be a `Map`, but you can create a `List` from the values of this map, if desired.

Here is an example:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class GroupByTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        example();
        exampleUnmaintainable();
    }


    private static void example()
    {
        List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(
            new Foo(1, "P1", 300, 400), 
            new Foo(1, "P4", 300, 400),
            new Foo(2, "P2", 600, 400),
            new Foo(3, "P3", 30, 20),
            new Foo(3, "P3", 70, 20),
            new Foo(1, "P1", 360, 40),
            new Foo(4, "P4", 320, 200),
            new Foo(4, "P4", 500, 900)
        );

        Function<Foo, Entry<Integer, String>> keyMapper = foo -> 
            new SimpleEntry<Integer, String>(foo.getId(), foo.getS());
        Function<Foo, Foo> valueMapper = foo -> foo;
        BinaryOperator<Foo> mergeFunction = (f0, f1) ->
            new Foo(f0.getId(), f0.getS(), f0.getX()+f1.getX(), f0.getY()+f1.getY());
        Map<Entry<Integer, String>, Foo> result = 
            foos.stream().collect(toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction));

        for (Entry<Entry<Integer, String>, Foo> entry : result.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(entry);
        }
    }


    private static void exampleUnmaintainable()
    {
        List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(
            new Foo(1, "P1", 300, 400), 
            new Foo(1, "P4", 300, 400),
            new Foo(2, "P2", 600, 400),
            new Foo(3, "P3", 30, 20),
            new Foo(3, "P3", 70, 20),
            new Foo(1, "P1", 360, 40),
            new Foo(4, "P4", 320, 200),
            new Foo(4, "P4", 500, 900)
        );

        List<Foo> result = foos.stream().collect(toMap(
            foo -> new SimpleEntry<Integer, String>(foo.getId(), foo.getS()), 
            foo -> foo, (f0, f1) -> new Foo(f0.getId(), f0.getS(), 
                f0.getX()+f1.getX(), f0.getY()+f1.getY())))
            .values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (Foo foo : result)
        {
            System.out.println(foo);
        }
    }


    static class Foo
    {
        private int id;
        private String s;
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public Foo(int id, String s, int x, int y)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.s = s;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getId()
        {
            return id;
        }

        public String getS()
        {
            return s;
        }

        public int getX()
        {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY()
        {
            return y;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Foo [id=" + id + ", s=" + s + ", x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
        }
    }

}
```

<sub>Yeah, a passive-aggressive remark: If you don't like the method names etc, then you should have shown us your actual `Foo` class. We **have** to guess a bit here...</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Use a method like this that will get every item from the first list, checks if it exists in the new list, if it doesn't the it just adds the item to the new list if it does then it adds the two last fields of the item to the item with the same first two fields that exists in the list.

```
public ArrayList<Foo> groupList(ArrayList<Foo> list){
    ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<Foo>();
    for(Foo foo: list){
        Foo temp = getFoo(foos, foo);
        if(temp != null){
            temp.merge(foo);
        }else{
            foos.add(foo);
        }
    }
}

public Foo getFoo(ArrayList<Foo> foos, Foo foo){
    for(Foo temp: foos){
        if(foos.equals(temp)){
            return temp;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And add these methods to your `Foo` class.
These assume that the fields of `Foo` are called `bar1`, `bar2`, `bar3` and `bar4`

```
public void merge(Foo otherFoo){
    this.setBar3(this.getBar3 + otherFoo.getBar3);
    this.setBar4(this.getBar4 + otherFoo.getBar4);
}

public boolean equals(Object object){
    if(object instanceof Foo){
        Foo otherFoo = (Foo)object;
        if(getBar1.equals(otherFoo.getBar1) && getBar2.equals(otherFoo.getBar2)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```